# Possibility to make multiple term selection in Managed Metadata navigation hierarchy?

Tags: navigation, managed-metadata, multiple-values, key-filter

I have a library set up with managed metadata navigation.
There are several thousand documents in this library.
One MM column is "theme", and almost each term has a child-term.
Another MM column is "Disease" where multiple selection is possible.
(It's a medical document library)

Example:
A document can be tagged with two themes and two diseases. As it can be related to all of them.

Navigation set up:
Themes are set up with hierarchy navigation.
Diseases are set up with Key Filters.

Problem:
By using the hierarchy with key filters, I can search only to a certain level. I need to go much deeper and find a specific cross-over document. A document tagged with two or more themes and two or more diseases.
The key filters allows for multiple choice.
However, the hierarchy navigation does not.

Ideally, it would be possible to select "Theme A" **and** "Theme F" in the navigation hierarchy panel, including their descendants. 
It is this kind of overlapping that is required in our organization. Some documents simply contain the strangest combinations of themes, and need to be easily found by people.

Is there a way to accomplish this level of filtering using OOTB elements?
Or some easy to implement javascript?

Environment set up:
SharePoint Server 2010 Std.
Windows XP SP3 (workstations).
IE 8.
MS Office 2007.

Comment: I have a similar issue - were you ever able to resolve?

Comment: No. Sorry. We still have this issue.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution in the meantime?